Characterization of normed spaces based on violation of parallelogram law
For a normed linear space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$, the Jordan-von Neumann theorem specifies when exactly the norm is induced via an inner product, namely when the parallelogram law is satisfied.
I would like to know if there is a reference for a normed linear space that violates the parallelogram law, but in only one direction. That is, for any non-zero $x \in X$ and $y \in X$, such that $x \neq \pm y$, the following holds:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2}{\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2} < 1.$$
In other words, the parallelogram law holds only when the vectors are equal or opposite.
Specifically, I'd like to know if such spaces, although they aren't Hilbert spaces, have nice properties that might be useful in their study.

This is equivalent to the full law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces

@EmilJeřábek  Yes $x+y=a, x-y=b$ mplies equality

@EmilJeřábek I added a clarification here. Sorry about the previous draft.

How is this not even stronger (and therefore just inconsistent for any nontrivial space) than your previous assumption?

If the above inequality holds for all nonzero $x,y$, then if all of $x,y,x+y,x-y$ are nonzero, we also have (applying your inequality to $x+y$ and $x-y$):
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{\|2x\|^2 + \|2y\|^2}{\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2}\leq 1,
$$
so $\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2 \leq 2(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2) \leq \|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2$, and we have the parallelogram identity.
Of course, if $x-y=0$ or $x+y=0$, the parallelogram identity is trivial.

Ah, I overlooked this. I will edit the question, because I have something else in mind.

Now the same argument goes through to simply show that no such normed spaces exist.

@AchimKrause Technically, if we’re being extremely pedantic, and if we count the zero space as a normed space, it does satisfy the requirement.

@DavidGao I’d call that slightly pedantic, if at all. Or does it mean that I am an extreme pedant?

@EmilJeřábek I mean, I felt like I was being overly pedantic when I wrote down my comment, given that I routinely ignored “trivial” objects when writing all sorts of arguments and it has worked well for me. So I felt I was being a bit hypocritical, which was why I added that phrase. It does seem too much an exaggeration now though. Depending on the field, ignoring trivial objects could be a quite bad idea, so I suppose it wouldn’t be pedantic at all if you’re in such fields.
